# MySQL / python conncector conversion arguments not working

Tags: python, mysql-connector

I am trying to use the following additional arguments in the mysql.connector.connect(), however when I run the following code it doesn't seem to have any effect.

```
import mysql.connector
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(
    ....
    raw='true',
    use_unicode='false'
)
cursor = cnx.cursor()
query = ("...")
cursor.execute(query)
result = cursor.fetchall()
print result
```

[(datetime.date(2015, 4, 5), 1243), ...

where the results has a column of MySQL datetime format values
but even with these arguments the output is still in python datetime.date(YYYY,M,D) format

same issue also when calling `col = cursor.column_names`, returns unicode instead of strings even though "raw" is set to true. 
print cursor.colun_names = (u'string_1', u'string_2')

is there some other configuration needed? i dont want to have to write code to convert these every time its used. thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you're supposed to be passing in string literals of 'true' and 'false' and not boolean values?

Comment: No errors in the code. I removed the single quotes and replaced with True / False boolean and am still getting the same result with the unicode column names. The datetime is now a bytearray(b'2015-04-05') which is a step in the wrong direction for me.

Comment: How did you get the data into the database in the first place?

Comment: it is an existing database I am working with, but can confirm that the field is a mysql "date" field. To clarify my goal, i would like the date output to be a string in the "2015-04-05" format so that it can be read easily

Comment: Looks like Alexander is right, check the documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html. Search for "date" and it says use raw=True.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think when Python evaluates something like:

```
if use_unicode:
   // do something
```

Variable `use_unicode` returns True, because string `'false'` evaluated to `True`. Try to use `Boolean` values.

```
import mysql.connector
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(
        ....
        raw=True,
        use_unicode=False
    )
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    query = ("...")
    cursor.execute(query)
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    print result

raw=True means:
```

> A MySQLCursorRaw cursor skips the conversion from MySQL data types to
>   Python types when fetching rows. A raw cursor is usually used to get
>   better performance or when you want to do the conversion yourself.

So you get ByteArray as expected. I don't know what exactly you are trying to do, but when I work with MySQL in Python, I prefer to work with dictionary data structure.

```
cursor = cnx.cursor(dictionary=True)
```

And then you will get result as dictionary. If you want to view it as string, just do `print str(dict)`

```
import mysql.connector
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user=self.username, password=self.password, host=self.host, database=self.database);
    cursor = cnx.cursor(dictionary=True)
    query = ("...")
    cursor.execute(query)
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    print str(result)
```

Comment: Thanks, the "raw" argument seems to be working, although I don't understand why it returns a bytearray instead of a string (as if you copy-paste from sql client). The "use_unicode" must not apply to cursor.column_names as it still returns unicode